# Show limit of $\arctan\left(\frac{x}{\pi}\right)$ as $x\rightarrow\infty$

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

I have been given the question $$\int^{\infty}_{0}\frac{dx}{x^2+\pi^2}=\frac{1}{2}$$

I have found the integral and obtained $$\int^{\infty}_{0}\frac{dx}{x^2+\pi^2} = \lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\int^{N}_{0}\frac{dx}{x^2+\pi^2}=\frac{1}{\pi}\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\left[\arctan\left(\frac{N}{\pi}\right)\right] $$  and came to sub in my limits of integration and I am unable to show that this limit does equal $\frac{\pi}{2}$ which would allow me to show the question is true. I need a full method of how to do it rather than saying "since the integral is = to $\frac{1}{2} $ then it must be $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: What is the tangent of $\frac\pi2$ ?

Comment: Shouldn't there be an N in that last arctan?

Comment: $\infty$? So can i say that because $\tan(\frac{\pi}{2})$ is $\infty$ then $\arctan{\infty} = \frac{\pi}{2}$?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Also $\tan \frac32\pi$ “is” $\infty$. Maybe also the definition for the inverse should be mentioned.

Comment: @redward01: review the definition of the arc tangent function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall that by definition for the [inverse of $\tan x$](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions) we have

$$\arctan x: \mathbb{R}\to \left(-\frac \pi 2,\frac \pi 2\right)$$

with $\arctan x$ strictly increasing.

Answer (score 1):

Hint : Let $\frac{x}{\pi}=\tan (t)$ where $t\in (-\pi/2,\pi/2)$. When does $\tan(t)$ go to $+\infty$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Recall the geometric meaning of $\tan^{-1}x$, as in the figure below. i.e. the angle, $\theta$, subtended by the line segment, $PQ=\tan\theta=x$, that is tangent to the unit circle at $P$. As **user** points out, this angle is assumed, by definition, to be the principal value, in $(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$.

When $Q$ is raised infinitely high, where does the intersection between $OQ$ and $PQ$ move to? And what would that imply about the lines $OQ$ and $PQ$? From this, you can infer what happens to $\theta=\tan^{-1}x$ as $x\to\infty$. This can then show you the range of $\tan^{-1}x$.

[image]

Comment: That’s the point indeed, maybe adding that the chosen range for the definition of the inverse is conventionally $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$.

Comment: @user Indeed, though I was trying to give an intuitive justification of why the value of the inverse is limited to that range.

Comment: I mean that also any other range as $(-\pi/2+2k\pi,\pi/2+2k\pi)$ would be fine and the concetion part of the definition is crucial.

Comment: @user Oh I see what you mean, that's a good point. I'll add that. Thanks.